Github Pages net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I am trying to host using github pages, but I get this error: GET https://alfieharris10.github.io/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Everything is named properly, and it works in localhost.
Here is the link to the github rep: https://github.com/AlfieHarris10/3D-Audio-Visualiser/tree/main
Here is the html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>3D Audio Visualiser</title>
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <input type="file" id="song" accept="audio/*" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 150px; padding: 10px;">
<button class="button">PLAY/STOP</button>

<script type="importmap">
  {
      "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.0/build/three.module.js",
          "three/examples/jsm/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.167.0/examples/jsm/",
          "shader-park-core": "https://unpkg.com/shader-park-core/dist/shader-park-core.esm.js"
      }
  }
  </script>

  <script type="module">
    import {
        Scene,
        PerspectiveCamera,
        WebGLRenderer,
        Color,
        Clock,
        AudioListener,
        Audio,
        AudioLoader,
        AudioAnalyser,
        Vector3,
        SphereGeometry
    } from 'three';
    import { createSculptureWithGeometry } from 'shader-park-core';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    
    const scene = new Scene();
    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 1.5;
    
    const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, transparent: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setClearColor(new Color(1, 1, 1), 0);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    const clock = new Clock();
    const listener = new AudioListener();
    camera.add(listener);
    
    const sound = new Audio(listener);
    let analyser = new AudioAnalyser(sound, 32);
    
    const state = {
        mouse: new Vector3(),
        currMouse: new Vector3(),
        pointerDown: 0.0,
        currPointerDown: 0.0,
        audio: 0.0,
        currAudio: 0.0,
        time: 0.0
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('pointermove', (event) => {
        state.currMouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        state.currMouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    }, false);
    
    window.addEventListener('pointerdown', () => state.currPointerDown = 1.0, false);
    window.addEventListener('pointerup', () => state.currPointerDown = 0.0, false);
    
    const geometry = new SphereGeometry(4, 90, 90);
    
    const mesh = createSculptureWithGeometry(geometry, spCode(), () => ({
        time: state.time,
        pointerDown: state.pointerDown,
        audio: state.audio,
        mouse: state.mouse,
        _scale: .5
    }));
    
    scene.add(mesh);

    
   let controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement, {
   enableDamping : true,
   dampingFactor : 0.25,
   zoomSpeed : 0.5,
   rotateSpeed : 0.5,
   } );

    
    const onWindowResize = () => {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
    
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('song');
    const button = document.querySelector('.button');
    
    const audioLoader = new AudioLoader();
    
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            audioLoader.load(url, (buffer) => {
                sound.setBuffer(buffer);
                sound.setLoop(true);
                sound.setVolume(0.5);
                sound.play();
                analyser = new AudioAnalyser(sound, 32);
            });
        }
    });
    
    let isPlaying = false;
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            sound.stop();
        } else {
            sound.play();
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    });
    
    const render = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        state.time += clock.getDelta();
        if (analyser) {
            state.currAudio += Math.pow((analyser.getFrequencyData()[2] / 255) * .81, 8) + clock.getDelta() * .5;
            state.audio = .2 * state.currAudio + .8 * state.audio;
        }
        state.pointerDown = .1 * state.currPointerDown + .9 * state.pointerDown;
        state.mouse.lerp(state.currMouse, .05);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    
    render();

function spCode() {
    return `
let audio = input();
let pointerDown = input();

setMaxIterations(5);
let s = getSpace();
let r = getRayDirection();

let n1 = noise(r * 4 + vec3(0, audio, vec3(0, audio, audio)) * .5);
let n = noise(s + vec3(0, 0, audio + time * .1) + n1);

metal(n * .5 + .5);
shine(n * .5 + .5);

color(normal * .1 + vec3(0, 0, 1));
displace(mouse.x * 2, mouse.y * 2, 0);
boxFrame(vec3(2), abs(n) * .1 + .04);
mixGeo(pointerDown);
sphere(n * .5 + .8);
`;
}

</script>

    

I can't even begin to think why this is, and after a lot of searching I still can't figure it out.

It looks like you are using react or some similar library, if so then there is different process to host a react website on git pages and if you using any other library or framework there is good chance that it has its hosting procedure. Follow this guide for react.

I don't think I'm using React. I have successfully hosted a similar project on Github pages where the only difference is that this project has a styles.css sheet (which is what is causing the error).

Instead of <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> use <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"> and it will.

Is it style or styles? And is it in a sub directory?

Styles. It seems that @Meet answer fixed the problem, but now I have this error, which I believe is an unrelated error, to do with Orbit controls: caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

@AHaworth Just noticed that in the code snippet I provided it uses 'style' not 'styles', thanks. I accidentally used a snippet with this previous error in that I had already changed, so for anyone reading with the same problem, try using ./styles.css

Besides the s, the URL in the question is missing the repo name in the path. https://alfieharris10.github.io/3D-Audio-Visualiser/styles.css works for me. Is that just an error in the question or is it a problem? Right now https://alfieharris10.github.io/3D-Audio-Visualiser/ seems to work fine, though, so I guess you've solved your problem already.

It was an error in the question, sorry for that. I have now resolved all issues and the page is hosting fine so I believe this can be closed now. Thank you all for your help!
